# Conditional Auto increment in xsl

Tags: xslt, auto-increment, xslt-2.0

I have an XML like this:

```
<V>
  <W>
    <X>1</X> 
  </W>
  <W>
    <Y>1</Y> 
  </W>
  <W>
    <X>1555</X> 
  </W>
  <W>
    <X>1</X> 
  </W>
</V>
```

I want to make it something like this:

```
<entity ID="start">
    <f ID="NewField">0001</f>
    <f ID="NewField">0001</f>
    <f ID="NewField">0002</f>
    <f ID="NewField">0003</f>
</entity>
```

When the field is V/W/X then `NewField` should be incremented by 1 as many times the tag V/W/X  is found.
Similarly for V/W/Y.

The XSL which I am using is

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<entity ID="start">
    <xsl:for-each select="V/W">
        <xsl:if test="X">
            <xsl:variable name="my_var">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('000',position())"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <f ID="NewField"><xsl:value-of  select="$my_var"/></f>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="Y">
            <xsl:variable name="my_var">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('000',position())"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <f ID="NewField"><xsl:value-of  select="$my_var"/></f>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</entity>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but it gives me a wrong result, something like this:

```
<entity ID="start">
  <f ID="NewField">0001</f>
  <f ID="NewField">0002</f> 
  <f ID="NewField">0003</f> 
  <f ID="NewField">0004</f> 
</entity>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to number nodes with XSLT then [the xsl:number element](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#number) can help:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <entity ID="start">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::X | descendant::Y"/>
    </entity>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="X | Y">
    <f ID="NewField"><xsl:number level="any" format="0000"/></f>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like `count(preceding::X)` expression. Of course you may want to make it more complex and then take care about number formatting, but that sounds like a starting point you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
  <xsl:template match="V">
    <entity ID="start">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="W/X|W/Y" />
    </entity>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="X|Y">
    <f ID="NewField">
      <xsl:variable name="counter" select="
        count(
          parent::W/preceding-sibling::W/*[name() = name(current())]
        ) + 1
      " />
      <xsl:value-of select="format-number($counter, '0000')" />
    </f>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This:

```
parent::W/preceding-sibling::W/*[name() = name(current())]
```

selects all preceding elements of the same name as the current element. E.g., if the point of execution is on this node:

```
<X>1555</X>
```

It goes one level up (`parent::W`), then selects all preceding `<W>` siblings, and of those it selects any child (`*`) that has a name of `X` - since `X` is the name of the `current()` element.

The resulting node-set is counted and incremented by one. `format-number()` is used to generate a nice clean output:

```
<entity ID="start">
  <f ID="NewField">0001</f>
  <f ID="NewField">0001</f>
  <f ID="NewField">0002</f>
  <f ID="NewField">0003</f>
</entity>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any particular reason why you use the `parent::` axis explicitly (which by definition only ever has at most one node) rather than `..` - it seems that it is rather unambiguous either way.

Comment: You are right, `'..'` is the same, and I know that. I'm doing it because for me it is more expressive. When reading the XPath, the anticipated document structure is clear instantly, whereas `'..'` leaves a rest of ambiguity.